# how to calculate a value by rules

Tags: rules, entities

I have three fields in a content type and want to calulate sum of them in another field.
First, I use [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) but it does not work at all.
Then I tried to use [conditional field](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) but it is not made for this purpose at all.
So I am trying rules module and make an event: After saving new content(or before) - The condition is: Content is of type [something] - The action: Execute custom PHP code.

And the code is:

```
$field_a = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_absence');
$field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_delay');
$field_c = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_vacation');
[node:field-sum] = $field_a[0]['value']+$field_b[0]['value']+$field_c[0]['value'];
```

But it does not do anything at all. I used the same code in computed field but it has no result. I'm not an expert Drupal programmer. So I need your helps in it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) module defines a new field type to dynamically calculate values on entity forms. This is an alternative to Computed Field
that does not require the use of PHP Filter.

**Note**: the above info is an excerpt from its project page.

Comment: that was a magic! I appreciate you and the module builder! have a nice day

Comment: Hm, I'm happy to read that there are "others" who seem to be aware of this (great) Math Field module! +1!

Comment: In the Drupal 7 rules 2 actions there, under Data, is "Calculate a value." I've been searching for days and cannot find one single example of how that field works. Can you provide an answer that uses that selector?